# How to convert object type to datetime64?

Tags: python, datetime, object

When I see the dtype, it seems to be object, but I cannot convert it to datetime64

```
0    2017-11-29 17:14:00
1    2017-02-15 15:35:00
2    2018-10-18 08:02:00
3    2017-06-22 09:25:00
4    2017-09-21 11:12:00
Name: Data e Hora Indução Anestesica, dtype: object
```

I have already tried this, but it does not work.

```
df['Data e Hora Indução Anestesica'].astype(str).astype(int)
hg = df['Data e Hora Indução Anestesica'].astype(str).str.zfill(6)
df['Data e Hora Indução Anestesica'] = pd.to_datetime(hg, format='%Y/%m/%d%H%M%S')
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do

```py
df['Data e Hora Indução Anestesica'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Data e Hora Indução Anestesica'])
```

Comment: I also tried that, but there's an error:
`
TypeError: <class 'datetime.time'> is not convertible to datetime
`

Comment: @bonaqua What error are you getting? Please update your question and post the full traceback if possible

Comment: TypeError: <class 'datetime.time'> is not convertible to datetime

Comment: @bonaqua Are you doing anything else beside the code you showed? The error states that your data is **time**, not **date**, yet your example seems to contradict that

Comment: I just import the libraries, read the excel and then do that (in order to avoid any other error in the middle)

Comment: When I do the dtypes in the very beginning, every feature that I have is datetime(as I want, except two of them.